# asp.net linq .contains "string"

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a field in a dataset and im querying using Linq my code is

```
 var countriesQry = from a in countTbl.AsEnumerable()
                               where a["CountryId"].ToString().Contains(countryId)
                               orderby a["CountryId"]
```

my problem is that in the "CountryId" field there can be a countryid of 1,22,13 (its a varchar field) so something can be a few countries. as you can guess its returning 1 and 13 if the "Countryid" = 1 can anyone tell how I can correct it

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `Contains` to `Equals`

```
var countriesQry = from a in countTbl.AsEnumerable()
                           where a["CountryId"].ToString().Equals(countryId)
                           orderby a["CountryId"]
```

Comment: yeah i initially thought of that but if the country field has the value "1,22,13" that wont return any results

Comment: sorry ill hold my hand up just tried.Equals and it works great thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var countriesQry = from a in countTbl.AsEnumerable()
                           where a["CountryId"].ToString().Equals(countryId)
                           orderby a["CountryId"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Any() instead of Contains.